# Creating button content with centered text and animated border

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers

The following XAML code creates a button with a border as its content. The border has a TextBlock as it's child. When you CLICK on the button, the border width gradually grows.
Since the text block is inside the border it is not seen until you click the button.
Now my requirements are:
There should be a text displayed on the button even before you click it.
Even after you click the button, only the border should animate while the button text remains in its center position.

```
<Button Name="button5" Width="100" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="94" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
<Button.Content>
    <Border Background="Gray" Width="0" Name="myBorder">
        <TextBlock>Search</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I will appreciate if anyone is able to provide answers with working XAML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your XAML only slightly:

```
<Button Name="button5" Width="100" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="94" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle x:Name="myRectangle" Fill="Gray" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock Text="Search" />
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

For the `Button`'s content, you could use a `Grid` which contains your `Border` and the `TextBlock`. Since no columns or rows are specified, the `TextBlock` and the `Border` are drawn on top of each other. It situations like this where the `Border` does not have content, I prefer to use a `Rectangle` instead since it is bit lighter. Hope this helps!